# Wallpapers I have on my phone

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualaikum so I watch anime a lot and keep anime wallpapers so is it permissible in Islam to keep such a wallpaper I would like to show one of the many of the wallpapers I use and please tell if they are permissible or not.[image: here are the images]

Answer (score 1):

This is not permissible due to the girl not covering her arwah (legs and knees) it should be covered from the knees so this goes to show this is prohibited and Allah knows best.